# What are the advantages to switch Amazon SES from the US to the EU?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I run a EU-based website on Amazon EC2, and currently send around 13,000 emails a day through Amazon SES. Much of the email throughput is during the early hours of the morning.

Now that Amazon SES has instances in Europe, are there any advantages to me switching from the current US-west SES servers into Europe? Does it make any difference in terms of deliverability or anything else?

The only benefit I can really see is one of *slight* speed increase; but email sending is done away from anything user-facing anyway.

Comment: This question would be better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: OK... my apologies. I will try to post this there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only advantage would be in terms pricing, only if you have the servers that are sending email in the same EC2 region as the SES region.  In other words if both of them are in the same region, you wouldn't get charged any "OUT" data.

Otherwise you would get charged $0.02 /GB . If you look at the AWS EC2 pricing here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ , it would be here:

[image: Pricing]

Of course, if your clients are outside Amazon you would get charged "IN" and "OUT" data.

Comment: Many thanks. My data transfer bill was $5.90 last month; including raw HTML pages from the webserver (which I assume is most of it). So, I don't need to worry about it; though I should set up new projects to use it, I suppose.